# Append Strings and values together to target a form control in VBA

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, variables, ms-access-forms

I'm so close to getting this code working, I just need a little push please. I would like to
take the name of a combo box and then add a string to the end, But then get the value of a textbox with that string. This is to create a dynamic function instead of pasting the same code over and over.

Here's what I have so far, after you select something in the dropdown, the data is then pulled to populate the boxes next to it. I have about 8 drop downs so far so that's why I need this to work.

```
'Combobox after update
Call GrabData(Me, Me.ActiveControl)
```

Then

```
Private Sub GrabData(ctl As Control)

  'name of ctl/combobox is "Kitchen"
  data1 = (ctl.Name & "Size") '"KitchenSize"

  'Here is where it all goes wrong 
   data1.Value = size.value 

  'size.value is just a textbox for example
    End Sub
```

I can debug this with:

```
msgbox(data1) 
   'outputs "KitchenSize"
```

But I cannot get the **value** of kitchensize's textbox with data1.value
**Error:**
Object Required

I have also added Dim As String / Dim As Control.

I will be assigning the variable to some other stuff in this 50 line code I wrote so please don't take the above example as exactly what I intend to do, I just need help appending the ctl.name to a string, then use that to reference another control and so on.

---

EDIT

---

For anyone who wants to know, I figured it out.

```
Dim Ctrl As Control
Dim CtrlName As String

CtrlName = ctl.Name & "Size"
Set Ctrl = Me.Controls(CtrlName)
Ctrl.Value = 'Wherever you want to send the values to
```

Comment: Though you already solved it, I thougth I mentioned VBA's little know [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function), which let's you achieve similar results. And not only restricted to controls, but objects (classes) in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the edit.

You need to dim it as a string, then use Set Ctrl

Comment: Please do not include the answer in the question. Instead put the code for the solution in the answer.